# Using .htaccess to map a random path to a private directory

Tags: htaccess, apache

I am trying to implement a zero downtime deploy strategy for a static website using an *.htaccess* file. I'd like to access at `http://example.com/__staging__` the staging enviroinment redirecting internally all the requests to the path containing the actual data uploaded (i.e. `http://example.com/__private__/abcdefgh` where `abcdefgh` is the hash of the commit). In the meantime opening directly anything under `http://example.com/__private__` should be forbidden.

This is the *.htaccess* file I have written so far (which does not work):

```
RewriteEngine On

# This line seems to work correctly.
RewriteRule "__staging__(.*)$" "__private__$1" [PT,E=__staging__:1]

# These directives always forbid the access while, to my understanding, should
# trigger after a rewrite from 
RewriteCond %{ENV:__staging__} "!=1"
RewriteRule "__private__" "-" [F]
```

I've read https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/env.html and https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/.. I have surely missed something, I am stuck. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why are you trying to use mod_rewrite for this purpose rather than using mod_alias?  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias

Comment: Thank you @StephenOstermiller for the tip! I've tried to use `Alias "/__staging__" "/__private__"` without luck. It is the only directive in the file at the moment. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Block direct access to __private__
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^__private__ - [F]

# Rewrite requests from __staging__ to __private__
RewriteRule ^__staging__(.*) __private__$1 [L]
```

There's no need to set the `__staging__` environment variable, unless you are using this for something else? (But you can always determine this from the requested URL in your app.)

The condition that checks the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var ensures we don't get a redirect loop. This is empty on the initial request and set to "200" (as in 200 OK HTTP status) after the first successful rewrite.

You should use a start-of-string anchor (`^`) to avoid potential conflicts. Regex is greedy by default, so the trailing `$` (end-of-string anchor) is superfluous on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

The surrounding double-quotes on the arguments are only strictly necessary if you have spaces in the argument values (even then they can be backslash escaped instead). So, whether you use double quotes here is just personal preference.

---

```
# These directives always forbid the access while, to my understanding, should
# trigger after a rewrite from 
RewriteCond %{ENV:__staging__} "!=1"
RewriteRule "__private__" "-" [F]
```

Because the `PT` flag (implies `L`) causes the rewrite engine to start over. At this point the environment variable `__staging__` is renamed to `REDIRECT___staging__` (`REDIRECT_` prefix - so that's 3 underscores in the resulting env var). So, the `__staging__` env var is never actually set at the time the rule is evaluated and the request is always blocked.

However, the method outlined above is the more usual way to handle this - no env var is required.